# Ejecutar .exe desde html

Tags: javascript, html

Buenas

Como podría hacer que al dar click en una imagen se ejecutara un programa de windows?

```
<img src="smiley.png" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">
```

Las imágenes las meto así al html ,y quiero que al dar click en esa imagen se ejecute por ejemplo el notepad.

He estado probando algunas cosas con javascript (windows.open) pero no he sido capaz.
Gracias

Comment: ya he ojeado y probado las cosas de ese hilo,pero ninguna funciona.Un metodo hace que se descarge el .exe y otro metodo hace que se abra una pagina web con la url del .exe

Comment: eso sería muyyy peligroso!!! Lo que harias es descargar el archivo y es el usuario el que decide si abrirlo y con que.

Comment: es cierto que por temas de seguridad, los navegadores no permiten a una página web acceder a los recursos del sistema. sin embargo hay muchos casos en los que si se puede hacer uso de lo que formulo el creador del post de que al dar click en una imagen se ejecute un programa de windows. sin ir mas lejos la plataforma de juegos [Roblox](https://www.roblox.com/) hace uso de dicha caracteristica, el usuario elije que juego quiere abrir en el navegador y al hacer el submit se abre el programa ya instalado en el computador para que se haga el deploy del juego previamente seleccionado. es cuestion d

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No se puede por temas de seguridad, ningún navegador permite a una página web acceder a los recursos del sistema salvo en casos muy puntuales (el único caso que conozco es para elegir un fichero para subirlo usando un input de tipo file).

El único escenario similar a lo que quieres es que desde una página te descargues un fichero .txt y el usuario ejecute el bloc de notas en lugar de simplemente descargarlo y guardarlo, pero sigue siendo elección del usuario.

Comment: estando en local también es imposible?Y no se puede hacer que la pagina web ejecute un script que esta en tu escritorio y ese script ejecute el programa?

Comment: Incluso estando en local, no hay manera de acceder o mandar ejecutar un fichero a menos que hablemos de Internet Explorer 8 o anteriores.

Answer (score 6):

Puedes probar con este script

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  function RunFile() {
    WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    WshShell.Run("c:/windows/system32/notepad.exe", 1, false);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Eso sólo funcionará con Internet Explorer, y sólo en versiones antiguas donde ActiveX aún no ha sido eliminado por inseguro

Comment: Esa respuesta la tienes aquí https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5422093/run-a-program-from-a-local-webpage

Comment: No veo motivos de dar esta respuesta como negativa, si esto funciona para IE y no se especifica en la pregunta que navegador necesita. No seais haters

Comment: pero el zoom si funcionna con un link, como es posible?

Comment: Jhon Jesus, no entiendo tu pregunta